# SQLite - Update after certain row

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to update rows after a certain id, but am unsure how. I got the id by taking a value from the last position of an arraylist, and then I passed that to my database helper.

```
private void addNewerOlderHashtags(List<Status> timeline)
{
    // get the last id of the arraylist 
    int lastId = Integer.parseInt(timeline_arg.get(timeline_arg.size() -1).get("sql_id"));

    for (int i=0; i < timeline.size(); i++){
        long tweetId = Long.parseLong(timeline_arg.get(i).get("tweet_id"));

        try {
            Status status = mTwitter.showStatus(tweetId);
            HashtagEntity[] entity = status.getHashtagEntities(); 
            List<String> hashlist = new ArrayList<String>(); 

            for (HashtagEntity hashtag : entity){ 
                String text = hashtag.getText(); 
                hashlist.add(text); 

                dbHelper.addNewerOlderHashtags(lastId, hashlist.toString()); 
            }
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Database Helper:

```
public void addNewerOlderHashtags(int id, String hashtags)
{
    try { 
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 

        values.put(COL_HASHTAG_ENTITIES, hashtags);

        String[] whereArgs = {Integer.toString(id)}; 

        db.update(TABLE_TWEETS, values, Tweets.COL_ROW_ID + ">?", whereArgs);
        db.close();         
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Is there an error or a crash or something?

Comment: You should not use a string for the rowid column, but if it is declared as INTEGER, the comparison will work anyway. What are you unsure about?